# Silex basic form submission

Tags: php, forms, frameworks, routes, silex

I am trying to add a payment gateway to my site. I am having a lot of trouble with the basic implementation of the Silex framework. The `app.php` page is never found. In fact, I am currently using a testing server and while the `signup.php` page is in the following directory:

`http://localhost/www/smafo/signup.php`,

submitting the form ends up resulting in the following url `http://localhost/create_transaction` which results in a page not found error.

**Note:** Changing the form's action attribute to `app.php`, routes to the correct `app.php` page and results in a Symfony Page not found error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

This is the sample form: `signup.php`

```
<form action="/create_transaction" method="POST" id="braintree-payment-form">
     <p>
       <label>Card Number</label>
       <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
     </p>
     <p>
       <label>CVV</label>
       <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-encrypted-name="month" /> / <input type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="year" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
 </form>
```

This is my app.php (in the same directory as signup.php)

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/', function () {
    include 'signup.php';
    return '';
});

$app->post('/create_transaction', function (Request $request) {
  echo 'YES';
  $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    'amount' => '1000.00',
    'creditCard' => array(
      'number' => $request->get('number'),
      'cvv' => $request->get('cvv'),
      'expirationMonth' => $request->get('month'),
      'expirationYear' => $request->get('year')
    ),
    'options' => array(
      'submitForSettlement' => true
    )
  ));

  if ($result->success) {
    return new Response("<h1>Success! Transaction ID: " . $result->transaction->id . "</h1>", 200);
  } else {
    return new Response("<h1>Error: " . $result->message . "</h1>", 200);
  }
});

$app->run();
```

I greatly appreciate any advice.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You're following this tutorial aren't u? https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/guide/getting_paid Aren't you missing the Javascript component?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am trying to follow the poor tutorial. No, I am not missing the javascript component.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually managed to solve it by making the following substitution:

```
<form action="app.php/create_transaction" method="POST" id="braintree-payment-form">
```